# Two mixed columns in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, multiple-columns

I have a data frame with two character vectors:

```
data.frame(
           matPA = c("PA66", "SB3", "PA66GF", "PA66", "SB2"), 
           matSB = c("SB1", "PA66", "SB1", "SB2", "PA66GF")
)
```

I want to have the right character in the right columns, e.g. PA66 & PA66GF to matPA and SB2 & 3 to matSB:

```
data.frame(
           matPA = c("PA66", "PA66", "PA66GF", "PA66", "PA66GF"), 
           matSB = c("SB1", "SB3", "SB1", "SB2", "SB2")
)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you show the logic

Comment: Can you explain what information you expect to use to differentiate between animals and colors? i.e., there must be *some* criterion you think the computer should use - do you have a list of animal names and/or color names stored that you plan to use?  Can you explain/justify why using `colors()` is *not* a workable solution for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
d <- data.frame(
           matPA = c("PA66", "SB3", "PA66GF", "PA66", "SB2"), 
           matSB = c("SB1", "PA66", "SB1", "SB2", "PA66GF")
)

library(dplyr)

d2 <- apply( d, 1, function(r) {
    r[ order( grepl("^SB",r)) ]
}) %>% t %>% as.data.frame %>% setNames( names(d) )
```

Like this perhaps.

Comment: Sorry I had to clarify my question. How can I solve the problem without the colors function?

Comment: sorry next try to clarify my problem. Hope this one is more clear.

Comment: right. that was quite the odd direction for this question to take. hope you learned more than some nifty R through all this.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the solution. Sure, I learned a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pmin`/`pmax` :

```
df <- transform(df, matPA = pmin(matPA, matSB), matSB = pmax(matPA, matSB))
df

#   matPA matSB
#1   PA66   SB1
#2   PA66   SB3
#3 PA66GF   SB1
#4   PA66   SB2
#5 PA66GF   SB2
```